# Run-length encoding giving wrong result

Tags: python, algorithm, encoding

I implemented a Run-length encoding that iterates through the input string, counting consecutive occurrences of each character. When the character changes, it appends the count followed by the character to the encoded string.

```
def run_length_encode(string):
    encoded = ""
    count = 1
    for i in range(1, len(string)):
        if string[i] == string[i - 1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            encoded += str(count) + string[i - 1]
            count = 1
    return encoded


# Example usage:
original_string = "AAAABBBCCDAA"
encoded_string = run_length_encode(original_string)

print("Original string:", original_string)
print("Encoded string:", encoded_string)
```

The issue is that the code I implemented does not count the last charater.
The above code return 4A3B2C1D instead of 4A3B2C1D2A.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before returning encoded you need to  append the count and character when the loop terminates `encoded += str(count) + string[-1]`

```
def run_length_encode(string):
    encoded = ""
    count = 1
    for i in range(1, len(string)):
        if string[i] == string[i - 1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            encoded += str(count) + string[i - 1]
            count = 1
    encoded += str(count) + string[-1]
    return encoded


# Example usage:
original_string = "AAAABBBCCDAA"
encoded_string = run_length_encode(original_string)

print("Original string:", original_string)
print("Encoded string:", encoded_string)
```